# Automatic proxy connection depending on the wi-fi network (Windows)

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy

When in my android phone, I can configure a different proxy for each wi-fi network. In my windows (Windows 10) tablet I can't do so, or at least not so directly.

So my question is:

Is it possible to do it via a configuration script?
If it is, how?

Configuration scripts: [Link1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361918.aspx) and [Link2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: A product such as [ProxySwitcher](https://github.com/mwiedemeyer/ProxySwitcher) could help (if still works for Windows 10).

Comment: You're in the wrong forum for this since it's a programming question, try Stackoverflow!

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Thanks. I thought it might not be technical enough for Stackoverflow. But still, thanks.

Comment: @Florian Why would this be a Stack Overflow question? This would get closed if it migrated over

Comment: @Canadian Luke, isn't writing a script programming question? The user is asking about how to program a script basically.

Comment: @florian the quality of the question, and stack overflow is not a script writing service. They expect the user to have code already that doesn't work, or a few other things that this question is not

Answer (score 1):

Follow the second link in your question. Create the file as, for example, `proxy.pac`. Save it to your hard drive on the root of c:.

In internet explorer's internet options-> connections-> advanced-> automatic configuration script, type `file://c:/proxy.pac`, then `ok` your way out.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the option to use a configuration script in the LAN Settings dialogue box. You can find this on the Connections tab of the Internet Properties page

Comment: That is something I know... and it's not the only way to get to the option of using configuration scripts... the problem was which configuration script to use.